# What Kind of C# Refactoring Options Exist for Visual Studio (and C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, visual-studio-express

Having now read Martin Fowler's "Refactoring," I would like to know what refactoring options are available in Visual Studio (Express especially, and for C# especially). The built-in IDE seems to just have Rename Variable and Extract Method; what's surprising is that 2003 (non-express) has around half-a-dozen refactorings.

What kind of tools and options are available, other than the IDE and refactoring by hand? I primarily use Express versions of Visual Studio, so brownie points for finding something that'll work without Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: Since VS Express versions do not support add-ins, you will have a hard time finding tools that can do this for you.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of money then you'd better have a lot of time.

Comment: SmallTalk's refactoring browser started out as an additional, third-party (non-IDE-integrated) tool. Since refactoring spread from there (according to Fowler, anyway) I have hopes that something exists. NUnit, PartCover, etc. all exist independently of the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of resharper by Jetbrains.  Worth every penny and then some.

Comment: And buy a better computer at once, because performance of VS.NET with R# sucks big time.

Comment: @lex-lavnikov Which version of VS are you referring to?  VS2010 is considerably more "sluggish" than 2008 due to the WPF implementation.  I noticed no performance degredation after installing Resharper.